# Creating tar.gz-archive from c++ program does not work

Tags: c++, linux, archive, tar

I use the following code snippet for creating a `tar.gz`-archive in an extensive measurement software. After collecting some data in several files I want to archive and compress them for later use.
Everything works fine when I start the program from the shell, all the data is collected and archived correctly.

However the program should start automatically after system start of an embedded Linux system. When it's started via a script in `/etc/init.d`, no data files are archived/compressed, even though I get the return value `0`. Furthermore, the tar.gz-file is created, but it's empty. 
Everything else is working fine.

Can anyone please explain, what I have to do in this special case of an automatic start?

```
int returnValue = -1;
std::string jobString = RESULT_PATH;
jobString += "/";
jobString += lastJobString;
std::string jobFiles = lastJobString + "*.*";

std::string cmd = "tar cvf - ";
cmd += jobFiles;
cmd += " | gzip > ";
cmd += jobString;
cmd += ".tar.gz";

std::cout << "archiving and compressing " << jobFiles << ": " << cmd << std::flush << std::endl;

returnValue = system(cmd.c_str());

std::cout << "archiving and compressing finished. Code: " << returnValue << std::flush << std::endl;
```

I know that there are several librariers, like `libarchive`, `libtar`, etc.  which to use is not as lazy as firing a system command, but I would like to know why this does not work for my case.

Furthermore, the version of `tar` in my busy box does not support option `z`.

Comment: Sometimes when starting programs from scripts, not all paths are set, so you have to use the full path, like `/bin/tar`. Your `.tar.gz` file will always be created as you are using the `>` operator, which creates an empty file on error. You could also redirect stderr to a log file to see the error message. You could also simply use `tar czf archive.tar.gz filenames` without manually invoking gzip and redirecting stdout to a file.

Comment: @Karsten Koop thanks for your answer. As I mentioned, I get no error as return value from the call. Furthermore the version of `tar`in my busy box has no option `z`.

Comment: Return 0 doesn't mean the command actually run. 
Even system("blabla 123 | gzip > out") would return 0 as I just tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem and maybe for all the cases when a system command is called by a daemon:

The trick is to create a new shell by the command `sh` and change the current directory before the tar-function is called:

```
std::string cmd = "sh -c \" cd ";
cmd += SOURCE_DIR;
cmd+= " && tar cvf - ";
cmd += jobFiles;
cmd += " | gzip > ";
cmd += jobString;
cmd += ".tar.gz";

returnValue = system(cmd.c_str());
```

Maybe this will help other users heading to the same problem.

Comment: Most `tar` programs (and certainly [GNU tar](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/)...) accept the `-C` program option to change directory. And you might call [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) in your C++ program.

Comment: Your system command is fragile and insecure: what if some malicious user would set `sourceDir` to `rm -rf $HOME`? Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) !!

Comment: `SOURCE_DIR` is a constant string defined in a header file.